# Set iPhone native popup's orientation

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, native-code, device-orientation

I've built a PhoneGap app for iPhone. In specific cases, landscape design and support was required, and so I've listened to device orientation notifications, and had my JS app add a '.landscape' css class which rotated the main container by 90 or -90 degrees.
This JS orientation handling was easy and quick, but the problem is the native interface is always portrait-oriented. When native popups are shown, they're always in portrait mode, even if the device is tilted to landscape.
Is there any way to set the orientation of native popups, without having to change the interface orientation (which is basically what I do in JS)?
Or do I have to rebuild the whole thing with proper native landscape orientation?